# Kubernetes/Container Engine: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-health-check, kubectl

About 7 hours ago i was working with kubectl without problems. Now (after a few hours of sleep, and a reboot of my computer) all kubectl get commands gives me this error:

```
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

I did not do anything since it worked besides shut down my computer.

Since I'm new with Kubernetes and GCE i need a few hints on what this could be, and where to look.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So i found the problem.

kubernetes was set to use the wrong context and cluster (i had created a GC project and deleted it again, and the created a new project).

I got the new credentials from GC:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME_FROM_GC
```

To get the new context name and cluster name i used:

```
kubectl config view
```

And to update the current context and cluster i used:

```
kubectl config set-cluster CLUSTER_NAME_FROM_CREDENTIALS
kubectl config set-context CONTEXT_NAME_FROM_CREDENTIALS
```

This fixed the problem.

Comment: I had the right context and cluster name already.. I updated it for the sake of it and it still doesn't work. Any idea why ?